# SQL Query to find missing rows returns syntax error

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ms-access, join

I try to filter missing values from two vectors. I try to compare two queries that work perfectly well seperately. However, when putting them together I seem to have missed something:

```
SELECT ID_Name FROM [000_Skalar_Daten] 
 WHERE VertragsPool       = 'Bestand' 
   AND Bilanzstichtag       = '20151231' 
   AND VR_Key               = '34' 
   AND Waehrung             = 'EUR' 
   AND SII_LINE_OF_BUSINESS = 'KLV' 
 WHERE ID_Name NOT IN (
      SELECT  distinct VD.ID_Name   
        FROM [000_Vektor_Daten] VD 
  INNER JOIN [000_Skalar_Daten] SD 
          ON VD.VertragsPool = SD.VertragsPool   
         AND VD.ID_Name = SD.ID_Name   
         AND VD.Bilanzstichtag = SD.Bilanzstichtag   
         AND VD.VR_Key = SD.VR_Key   
         AND VD.Waehrung  = SD.Waehrung   
       WHERE SD.VertragsPool       = 'Bestand' 
         AND SD.Bilanzstichtag       = '20151231' 
         AND SD.VR_Key               = '34' 
         AND SD.Waehrung             ='EUR' 
         AND SD.SII_LINE_OF_BUSINESS ='KLV'
    )
```

Returns syntax error near `WHERE` clause. My question is how do I restructure the query to return only values that are not in the second query part. Maybe it is relevant that I pass this query via a *pass-through-query* in MS Access to a Microsoft SQL-Server.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Replace the second `WHERE` with `AND`.

Comment: Also, no need for `SELECT DISTINCT` in the sub-query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Already the error's reason has been mentioned in comments. Here is a better way to write your query which handles `NULL` values from `Sub-Query`

```
SELECT ID_Name
FROM   [000_Skalar_Daten] a
WHERE  VertragsPool = 'Bestand'
       AND Bilanzstichtag = '20151231'
       AND VR_Key = '34'
       AND Waehrung = 'EUR'
       AND SII_LINE_OF_BUSINESS = 'KLV'
       AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                       FROM   [000_Vektor_Daten] VD
                              INNER JOIN [000_Skalar_Daten] SD
                                      ON VD.VertragsPool = SD.VertragsPool
                                         AND VD.ID_Name = SD.ID_Name
                                         AND VD.Bilanzstichtag = SD.Bilanzstichtag
                                         AND VD.VR_Key = SD.VR_Key
                                         AND VD.Waehrung = SD.Waehrung
                       WHERE  SD.VertragsPool = 'Bestand'
                              AND SD.Bilanzstichtag = '20151231'
                              AND SD.VR_Key = '34'
                              AND SD.Waehrung = 'EUR'
                              AND SD.SII_LINE_OF_BUSINESS = 'KLV'
                              AND a.ID_Name = VD.ID_Name)
```